# Can someone explain this Python code for me?

Tags: python, pty

This code create pty (pseudo-terminals) in Python. I have commented the parts that I do not understand

```
import os,select
pid, master_fd =os.forkpty() #I guess this function return the next available pid and fd 
args=['/bin/bash']
if pid == 0:#I have no I idea what this if statement does, however I have noticed that it get executed twice
    os.execlp('/bin/bash',*args)
while 1:
    r,w,e=select.select([master_fd,0], [], [])
    for i in r:
        if i==master_fd:

            data=os.read(master_fd, 1024)
            """Why I cannot do something like 
               f=open('/dev/pts/'+master_fd,'r')
               data=f.read()"""
            os.write(1, data) # What does 1 mean???
        elif i==0:

            data = os.read(0, 1024)
            while data!='':
                n = os.write(master_fd, data)
                data = data[n:]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Unix-like operating systems, the way to start a new process is a *fork*. That is accomplished with `fork()` or its several cousins. What this does is it duplicates the calling process, in effect having two exactly the same programs.

The only difference is the return value from `fork()`. The parent process gets the PID of the child, and the child gets `0`. What usually happens is that you have an if statement like the one that you're asking about.

If the returned PID is `0` then you're "in the child". In this case the child is supposed to be a shell, so `bash` is executed.

Else, you're "in the parent". In this case the parent makes sure that the child's open file descriptors (`stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` and any open files) do what they're supposed to.

If you ever take an OS class or just try to write your own shell you'll be following this pattern a lot.

---

As for your other question, what does the `1` mean in `os.write(1, data)`?

The file descriptors are integer offsets into an array inside the kernel:

- 0 is `stdin`
- 1 is `stdout`
- 2 is `stderr`

i.e. that line just writes to `stdout`.

When you want to set up pipes or redirections then you just change the meaning of those three file descriptors (look up `dup2()`).

Comment: Good explanation  , but do the parent and the child run in parallel ??

Comment: And what happens to the child's stdout and stdin do they get redirected to the parent ??

Comment: The two processes are *identical*. That means they have identical `stdout`, etc. If you want redirection then you have to set it up yourself.